# Catch duplicate exception in ng-repeat table Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, exception

I'm Trying to notify the user each time a duplicate is registered in a table. I would like to catch the: `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]` and alert the user before proceeding. Here is the controller method adding elements to the table:

```
$scope.addProdukt = function (item) {
    kladdValidationService.checkTable(); 
    try {
        $scope.addedResult.push(item); // works fine
        logService.info('Produktet er lagt til i tabellen'); 

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.stack); 
        console.log($exceptionHandler(e)); // neither of these two work
    }
    console.log($scope.addedResult);
};
```

Every time I push an already added item to the table, the `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]` outputs in the console. Juswt not sure how to catch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the error isn't caught is because pushing the duplicate into the array is perfectly valid and doesn't cause an exception. the exception happens in the `ng-repeat` directive.

If you wish to notify your user when they try to add a duplicate try something like this:

```
$scope.addProdukt = function (item) {
    if(addedResult.indexOf(item) != -1){
        console.log("You tried to add a duplicate");
    }else{
         $scope.addedResult.push(item);
    }
}
```

If you wanted to warn the user about a duplicate but still let them have duplicates then you can show it in the html by adding `track by $index` in your `ng-repeat`
i.e:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $scope.addedResult track by $index">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try followings:

**track by $index** always remove the duplicasy

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">
  {{n}}
</div>
```

Comment: The duplicate by itself is not the issue. My problem is that a duplicate in the table produces a unvalid state that the user can't see unless the console is open. I need to load an alert for example, to make the user coorect their mistake

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to catch the: Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] and alert the user before proceeding.

To show to the users that your code crashed with Exception?

Its not good practice to catch Exceptions of your code and notify users about. Keep in mind that after `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]` - your code doesn't work properly! It can cause to unexpected behavior. Digest cycle stops and so on.

I strongly suggest you to write logic that searches in arrays duplicate ids and notify users.

**Don't use Angular Exception flow for your needs!**

---

Anyways if you want to manage exceptions, you can catch override `$exceptionHandler` :

For example:

```
app.config(function($provide) {

   $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", function($delegate, $injector) {
    return function(exception, cause) {

            var data = {
                message: "Exception: " + exception.message,
                stack: exception.stack || "none"
            };

             // manage your exception
             alert(JSON.stringify(data));


            // Call The original Angular Exception Handler
            $delegate(exception, cause);

       };
   });

});
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tmV8EVcvgCBqGQEiqt2u?p=preview)</kbd>

After you can inject some service and pass all Exception data there:

```
// ...
var someService = $injector.get("SomeService"); 

someService.reportClientError(data).then(function(data) {
               //...
            }, function(error) {
                //...
            });
```

---

Comment: The array containg the items added and the table rendering them are seperate. ng-repeat will only show the item once even though its added twice in the array which will be used later in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Something along this lines? Unfortunately, I can not test this right now but the core was taken from anguarJS sample code that describes how to log exceptions

```
angular.
module('exceptionOverwrite', []).
factory('$exceptionHandler', [function() {
var exceptions = [];
return function myExceptionHandler(exception, cause) {
   if(exceptions.indexOf(exception) !== -1) 
    {// its duplicate do your thing
     }
   this.exceptions.add(exception)
};
}]);
```